# AHK SetTitleMatch cannot match with webpages

Tags: windows, match, title

I cannot set up a script when trying to use just part of the Window Title of a webpage using Internet Explorer or Chrome

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive, bab.la Italian-English dictionary - Internet Explorer ahk_class IEFrame
!space::
msgbox hello
return
#IfWinActive
```